Topos as a totally cocomplete object in a 2-category CART
In the preface to Sketches of an elephant, Peter Johnstone gives a list of characterizations of topos, some applicable to elementary (ii- finite limits and power objects) other to Grothendieck (i- category of sheaves on a site) topoi. With first seven and the one I am curious about attributed as a list to André Joyal's lecture at the 1981 Cambridge Summer Meeting on Category Theory. This is (v) on the list.

A topos is a totally cocomplete object in the meta-2-category CART of cartesian (i.e., finitely complete) categories

Based on the mention of total cocompleteness this seems to be a characterization of Grothendieck topoi. It is reminiscent of the characterization of Grothendieck topoi as found on nLab as 2.3. I am looking for a reference of this claim of total cocompleteness in the 2-category of cartesian categories characterizing Grothendieck (or elementary) topoi. Possibly this is the same characterization as 2.3, but paraphrased without the size restriction. Anyone knows what the state of affairs here is, has a reference of where this comes from other than the Joyal's lecture?

My understanding is that the list at the start of Sketches is an intuition, not meant as a precise characterisation. Certainly at the time Joyal gave the lecture in 1981, it was not known whether every lex-total category in the sense of Street–Walters is a Grothendieck topos without the size constraint (see Street's Notions of topos).

@varkor It being an intuition rather than a precise theorem would explain the apparent contradiction.
